# Error conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am inserting date into database, and I get this error

> The conversion of a `varchar` data type to a `datetime` data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

My database is like

```
column   datatype
-----------------
id       int
date     datetime
```

My current date format is `DD/MM/YYYY`. but it didn't accept. When I changed format (made changes in system calender not in programming) to `YYYY/DD/MM`, it works.

Why does the above format not work?

My query is

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblnewaccount values ('" + id + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "')", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: you should use parametrized queries, read up on sql injection

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the above format not work?

I honestly don't *care* and **neither you should.** Because you are doing something terribly wrong here than using the right format.

You try to save your [`DateTime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) values with their `string` representation in a [`datetime`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) typed column. You should always choose the right data type for your values.

- [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

First, don't use `Text` property of your `DateTimePicker`, use [`Value` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) to get the value as a `DateTime`. And you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

```
using(var con = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into tblnewaccount
                        values (@id, @date)";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It wont work because it will be recognized as a `string` instead of a valid `DateTime` object value. You can try converting it to a valid datetime format so that it can recognize it. Also, you can show the `text` value as dd/MM/yyyy like you are showing now, but pass the `value` parameter in your query if it gives you a proper datetime format.

Have a look into Conversion from string to datetime as well. That will give you clear idea in this case.

Hope this helps.